# the Path with space provided as argument is throwing error in C#

Tags: c#

I'm passing an arguments as  "iTest.SolutionsBuilder(wsPath + "Out" + @"Test Out");" since there is a white space in the folder 'Test Outgoing' the code fails to run.     If I Step into SolutionBuilder method the path is shown as below wspath\OutTest Out   instead of wspath\OutTest\Test Out.  Please help to address this issue in C# on Visual Studio 2017. The error is "Could not find a part of the path"
Note: wspath holds the path of D:\coderun\unittest\

The code snippet is below

```
public void iTest_Build_SSIS_Solutions()
{
try
{
string wsPath = unittest.LocalPath; 
//wspath = D:\coderun\unittest\
Logger.Info(string.Format("New config updated"));
iTest.SolutionsBuilder(wsPath + "Out", "Testing");  - This works fine
iTest.SolutionsBuilder(wsPath + "Out", "Test Out");  -this is throwing error because of white space
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
throw ex;
}
}
```

Comment: I totally don't get why you expect "Test\" part to show up in the code shown... Please review your actual code and make sure that code in the post actually matches what you have (review [MCVE] guidance as it may help to clarify how much code is needed)

Comment: sorry I did not get mjwills, are you saying that quotes should be provided as below          iTest.SolutionsBuilder("wsPath + "Out" + @"Test Out"");

Comment: Your best bet when composing paths is to use `Path.Combine`; it handles slashes correctly.  But, reading your code, you have `"D:\coderun\unittest\" + "Out" + "Test Out"`.  That should show up as `"D:\coderun\unittest\OutTest Out"` by my understanding of string arithmetic, not `"wspath\OutTest\Test Out"` (I have no idea how you would think that should be the answer)

Comment: I've updated the complete code for that method -Please check and confirm

Comment: What is `iTest`? What is the `SolutionsBuilder` method? Show the code.

Comment: Is `SolutionsBuilder` your code or come from some library.  Searching the internet for "SolutionsBuilder" turns up a lot.  What type is `iTest`?

Comment: this is exiting framework, I'm just calling existing methods in framework, I just need to access the folder with space 'Test Out'

Comment: Let me just reiterate what @Flydog57 commented -- use `Path.Combine` example: `var myPath = Path.Combine(wsPath, "Out", "Test Out");` will return "D:\coderun\unittest\Out\Test Out". But if you want "D:\coderun\unittest\OutTest Out" you must use: `var myPath = Path.Combine(wsPath, "OutTest Out");`

Comment: Oh thanks a lot Flydog57 and Barns. Appreciate all your help!

Comment: @Raj - Did you read the page at the [mcve] link thoroughly?

Comment: Yes Enigmativity -- Yes I'll provide as much as info possible shortly in future.

Comment: @Raj.  It may be an existing framework, but without any knowledge of that framework (like even the `SolutionsBuilder` method signature - your original code was passing a single string, your updated code passes two strings), we really can't help you.  You really should have posted the method declaration and some of whatever documentation you might have.

Comment: Yes I understood Flydog57, it's lot of methods within that framework, would be lot of info to be provided and difficult to summarize. Thanks a lot for all your support.

Comment: @Raj - "t's lot of methods within that framework, would be lot of info to be provided and difficult to summarize." - and without it it is difficult for us to answer. You should do the work required to make the question easy to answer. Questions with good detail get answered within minutes. If a question does not have an answer after an hour then it needs improvement.